# operator<< doesn't find match

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

```
    class Shape
    {
        virtual void out() = 0;
    };

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Shape& a)
    {
        return os << a.out();
    }
```

I want to create an abstract base class and be able to simply use cout << Triangle/Square etc. later on, with Triangle, Square being derived classes from Shape.

It works fine if I simply say `return os << "test";`  so I'm guessing it's something to do with a.out() not getting called properly, I just can't seem to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: How are you calling the operator?

Comment: You should be taking `a` by const reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `out` member function returns `void`, so it doesn't return an object for you to pass to  `std::ostream::operator<<`. Perhaps you want it to return `std::string`?

Comment: wow right, I wanted to simply call the function from this operator then I realized (if I'm correct) I have to pass it something, and completely forgot about the original function being void.

Can I not pass the os anything in the operator<< or should I just pass a string from the out function?

Comment: @SaintHUN Either pass the stream as an argument to the function and keep it `void`, or let the function return a string. I recommend the first alternative.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks, and sorry for such an easy question. :)